# AWS Api Gateway querystring collection format multi

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway

We are currently importing our API from a swagger file where we have a query string parameter defined as

```
- name: sort
  in: query
  description: The sort key and direction.
  required: false
  type: string
  collectionFormat: multi
```

However there doesn't seem to be an equivalent `x-amazon-apigateway-integration.requestParameters` to support `collectionsFormat: multi`. When I send an API request like `?sort=price,DESC&sort=created,ASC` it only passes the last sort parameter to my integration.

Does anyone know if this is supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not supported in API Gateway at the moment.

Thanks!
Ritisha.